# Download Tumblr messages

Tags: download, message, tumblr

I would like to download certain direct messages from my Tumblr account, preferrably including emojis and images.
Is there a way to do that?

TumblThree and tumblr-utils don't seem to have that functionality.
Unfortunately, I cannot get the tumblr-chat-messages-downloader PHP script to work. Maybe it's outdated? It just displays the readme message without downloading anything.

Thanks a lot in advance for your support!